# Espresso: click() on SwitchCompat not working

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager`, on page 3 there is a `SwitchCompat` I want to perform a `click()` on, but it does nothing.

```
@Test
public void checkSummaryPageUpdates_worksCorrect() {

    onView(withId(R.id.view_pager)).perform(swipeLeft());
    onView(withId(R.id.view_pager)).perform(swipeLeft());

    onView(withId(R.id.gs_switch)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.gs_switch)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.gs_switch)).check(matches(isChecked())); //  AssertionFailed

}
```

This is the error

> android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with checkbox state: is ' doesn't match the selected view.
>   Expected: with checkbox state: is true

The SwitchCompat seems to have the following properties:

> Got: "SwitchCompat{id=2131689643, res-name=gs_switch, visibility=VISIBLE, width=996, height=100, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=GLÜCKSSPIRALE +5,00 €, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}"

The error says that the Switch is not checked, but the problem seems to occur before, cause the Switch just stays unchecked, the `perform(click())` seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I posted an alternate solution that involves creating a custom ViewAction to set switch state (or any Checkable for that matter) instead of using a click action. This ensures that your action is state independent.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39650813/1947601

So, no matter if it was previously checked or not, you're guaranteed that it will be toggled to the state you expect.

Comment: Yes thank you I just used this and it works great. However, why is the click() not working? Isn´t it supposed to work just with a perform.click()?